# Is it possible to change the autoscroll offset when dragging?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a single-page app written in Vue.js. The UI comprises three main elements:

- a navbar with `position: fixed` at the top and `z-index: 2`
- a sidebar with `position: fixed` on the left and `z-index: 1` and padded to account for the presence of the navbar
- a central area, padded to account for the presence of the other fixed elements.

The sidebar is scrollable with `overflow-y: auto`. Some elements in the sidebar, that I designated here with the text `item X`, are **draggable**.

Normally, when dragging towards the edges of a scrollable area, the area will automatically scroll in that direction. In my application the sidebar does not auto-scroll, because the upper edge is hidden by the navbar.

An obvious solution would be to change the structure of the sidebar so that its upper edge lies visible instead of being one top-padded div. However this might break other things.

**Question:**
I would like to know if there's a way to trigger auto-scroll on drag when the mouse is arbitrarily close to the edge, e.g. $navbarHeight pixels.

I'm looking for a pure HTML5 solution, vanilla js, or something with my current framework (Vue.js v3).

**What I already tried:**
I've done a great deal of googling but I'm probably using the wrong search queries: "auto scroll while dragging", "scroll sensitivity area", "autoscroll offset", and several combinations of quotes did not yield relevant results.

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/7f5wh1mj/4/

**What the page looks like** (see the fiddle for a working example):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays, you may use grid to create such layouts , here is an example without position but grid ;)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        text: "Learn JavaScript",
        done: false
      },
      {
        text: "Learn Vue",
        done: false
      },
      {
        text: "Play around in JSFiddle",
        done: true
      },
      {
        text: "Build something awesome",
        done: true
      }
    ],
    items: 12
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo) {
      todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* reset , optionnal */
}

body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  /* needed */
  width: 100vw;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  /* do not remove */
}

.navbar {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  /* z-index: 1; no need */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  /*  z-index: 0; no need */
  overflow: auto;
  /* make it scroll too instead body */
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

aside p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background:gray;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0.25em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="navbar">
    <h1>Navbar</h1>
  </div>
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <p>Sidebar</p>
    <ul>
      <li draggable v-for="n in items">item {{ n }}</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Todos:</h2>
    <ol>
      <li v-for="todo in todos">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="toggle(todo)" v-bind:checked="todo.done">

          <del v-if="todo.done">
            {{ todo.text }}
          </del>
          <span v-else>
            {{ todo.text }}
          </span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

***edit :** added comment and a sticky example inside the sidebar.*

Comment: @blackgreen it does here in the snippet, bottom elements will scroll once the grid is too small to hold them . height on body and App is taking care of it. keep it. z-index are also of no use, i did not entirely clean/removed the unnecessary rules ;)